# user input searched in database mysql python 3.4

Tags: python, mysql, python-3.4, fuzzy-logic

I am trying to take input from user and search that in database table. but my if statement is not working properly , It shows same results for values that exists and values that does not exist. Students table containing first_name, last_name , age , income , degree
and i am taking age as user input. if statement does not work correctly.
here is my code: I tried many different scenario's

```
import pymysql
db= pymysql.connect("localhost","testuser","admin","TESTDB")
cursor =db.cursor()
age= input("Please select a age:\n")
cursor.execute(f"SELECT AGE FROM STUDENTS WHERE age={age}")
results=cursor.fetchall()
print(results)
if (results ==age):
        print("age exit!")
else:
        print("not exists")

try:
        db.commit()
except:
        db.rollback()

        db.close()
```

Comment: Firstly, you should not be using string formatting for queries as that's an SQL injection risk. Second, your result with be returned as a tuple containing one item, so you'll need to take the `[0]` index on the result to get at the actual value.

Comment: thanks , but my if statement is not working , i used results=cursor.fetchall()[0]
 as well , it only shows one value but the problem is if statement is not working.

Comment: Try `print(repr(results), repr(age))`. The number `83` is not the same thing as (and not equal to) the string `"83"`. Is that your problem? (I mean on top of the `[0]` problem, which is _also_ a probem, which you still haven't solved.)

Comment: Also, why are you trying to commit or rollback a transaction where you didn't do any changes? And why are you only closing the database if the commit fails, and otherwise leaking it?

Comment: Meanwhile, `cursor.fetchall()` returns a list of one tuple of one item, not a tuple of one item. So you actually need `[0][0]`—first to get the first (only) row in the results, and then to get the first (only) column in that row.

Comment: I think it might be more a case of `results = [item[0] for item in cursor.fetchall()]`

Comment: look . Please select a age:
28
((28,), (28,))
not exists               This is my output of code , 28 exists in my database but if statement is not working , it should display age exists.

Comment: It's worth reading the previous comments because it isn't actually straightforward to see how your current code should work

Comment: @abarnet  i dont know y if statement is not working , i just try to compare user input to my database values , can u help ion code ?

Comment: @roganjosh i just want to compare the user input to database values and show that the value exists and value does not exist .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm trying to go off your question and your comments. Maybe you want something like the following where you rely on a falsey value on a failed lookup:

```
import pymysql
db= pymysql.connect("localhost","testuser","admin","TESTDB")
cursor =db.cursor()
age= input("Please select an age:\n")

cursor.execute("SELECT age FROM STUDENTS WHERE age=%s", (age,))
data = cursor.fetchall()
if data:
    print("Age exists")
else:
    print("Age does not exist")
```

This kind of lookup does not require any kind of `commit` or `rollback`, you're just querying the database, so the latter part of your code doesn't make sense to me.

Your current query will return all cases where `age` is equal to your current value. If the purpose is just to see whether it *exists* then you can limit the query and use [`fetchone()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-api-mysqlcursor-fetchone.html) instead.

```
cursor.execute("SELECT age FROM STUDENTS WHERE age=%s LIMIT 1", (age,))
```

Comment: yeah dats wt i needed :) thnx

Comment: @Rida Does it actually work for your problem? It could be more efficient for this purpose if it does what you want.

Comment: yes!   it compares and giving accurate result . how to make it efficient ?